# How to branch if-statements in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, syntax-error, branch, statements

I've just started learning Batch, although I can't figure out the syntax for branching if-statements inside other if-statements. As in,

```
@echo off
set first=
set second=
set /P first=first?: %=%
if /I "%first%"=="y" (
     echo a.1
     set /P second=second?: %=%
     if /I "%second%"=="y" (
          echo b.1
     ) else if %second%=="n" (
          echo b.2
     ) else (
          echo b.3
     )
) else if /I "%first%"=="n" (
     echo a.2
) else (
     echo a.3
)
pause
```

Any help with that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IF logic is perfectly fine. Your problem is you need delayed expansion. `%second%` is expanded when the statement is parsed, and the entire complex IF logic is parsed in a single pass. So `%second%` expands to the value that existed before the IF statement is executed, which in your case is an empty string.

The solution is to enable delayed expansion and then use `!second!` to expand the value. Delayed expansion occurs after the statement is parsed.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set first=
set second=
set /P first=first?: %=%
if /I "%first%"=="y" (
     echo a.1
     set /P second=second?: %=%
     if /I "!second!"=="y" (
          echo b.1
     ) else if "!second!"=="n" (
          echo b.2
     ) else (
          echo b.3
     )
) else if /I "%first%"=="n" (
     echo a.2
) else (
     echo a.3
)
pause
```